# MVC (модели)

Tags: база-данных, mvc, архитектура, orm

Допустим у меня есть 2 модели: Комментарии и Посты. Стоит задача выбрать посты у которых комментариев больше 3. Что бы сделать такой запрос  мне необходимо написать примерно такой SQL: `select * from posts where (select count(*) from commets where comments.post_id = posts.id) > 3`. Видно что этот код относится к разным моделям:

- `select * from posts where (*) > 3` относится к постам
- `select count(*) from commets where comments.post_id = posts.id` относится к комментариям.

По идеи я могу сделать так:

```
class Comment:
   def getCommentCountByPostId(id):
      SQL("select count(*) from comments where comments.post_id = " + id);

class Post:
   def getPosts():
      SQL("select * from posts where (" + 
           Comment.getCommentCountByPostId("posts.id") + 
      ") > 3")
```

Но что если я захочу хранить комментарии, скажем, не в реляционной базе данных, например в mongodb или вообще не в базе данных? Тогда при внесении таких изменений придется переписать достаточное большое количество кода. Следовательно код, написанный выше, не верен. Мы можем модернизировать код следующим образом:

```
class Comment:
   def getPostIdsWhereCommentsGt3():
      SQL("select post_id from (
          select count(*) as 'count', comments.post_id 
          from comments group by comments.post_id
          ) where count > 3").execute()

class Post:
   def getPosts():
      ids = Comment.getPostIdsWhereCommentsGt3()
      SQL("select * from posts where id in (" + ids.join(',') + ")")
```

Но тогда получается один лишний запрос. Какие решения применяют в таких случаях или нужно жертвовать производительностью во имя слабой связанности?

Comment: Зачем вам свой собственный ORM?

Comment: где вы видите здесь свой орм? здесь вопрос архитектурной организации

Comment: Причем здесь MVC? Все что вам нужно сделать, это раздлеить логику доступа к данным (непосредственно CRUD операции) и бизнес логику. Для этого достаточно ввести промежуточный сервисный слой, который будет обращаться к слою DAO. При этом вы можете ввести сколь угодно много реализаций DAO и заменять их в сервисном слое путем конфигурирования или даже использовать сразу несколько.

Что касается сущностей посты и комментарии, то оставьте один запрос и поместите его в DAO, который работает с постами, т.к. возвращаете вы именно посты.